# How to display and edit Collection of an object property in grid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a collection of objects which I want to display them into a `DataGrid`. The problem that inside my collection there is a collection of nested type
which I need to display them also in the same grid. Please find below my colelction of objects:

```
public class DataSource
  {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Block> Children { get; set; }

  }

public class Block
{
    public string BlockName { get; set; }

    public int BlockNumber { get; set; }

    public string BlockAdress { get; set; }

    public string BlockStatus { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection SourceData { get; set; }
```

***My Xaml***

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <DataGrid Name="DgDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="1*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Name" Binding="{Binding BlockName}" Width="1*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Number" Binding="{Binding BlockNumber}" Width="1*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Adress" Binding="{Binding BlockAdress}" Width="1*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BlockStatus" Binding="{Binding BlockStatus}" Width="1*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel

>
```

How can I display the list of blocks in my `DataGrid`. Please find  at the attached image how I want my GridControl to behave.

[image: DataGrid Complex column Binding]

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="DataGrid_Test">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Childrens">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Name" Binding="{Binding BlockName}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Number" Binding="{Binding BlockNumber}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Adress" Binding="{Binding BlockAdress}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="BlockStatus" Binding="{Binding BlockStatus}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Well i thought to do something like this but that's  not what i want since you will have at the tope an empty header